# Error while using materialize css table

Tags: php, wordpress, materialize

I have a php file designed to retrieve information from database. The problem is that if i use a normal table tags like the following it would work and show the page for me.

```
<?php /*Template Name: contactread */
  get_header();
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "***** (for security purpose only)";
  $password = "*****";
  $dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM contact";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

echo "<table class='table'>
<tr>
<th class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-top: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>نام</th>
<th class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-top: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>ایمیل</th>
<th class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-top: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>پیام</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tda' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #313131; border-right: 1px solid #313131;'>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And When i use it like the following which is calling everything from the framework, it gives me the http 500 error. (I included the entire page for showing the first type of table so you have the idea of the page, however i dont see a reason to re write it all again)

```
echo "<table>
         <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>نام</th>
               <th>ایمیل</th>
               <th>پیام</th>

           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
           echo <tr>
           echo  <td>. $row['name'] .</td>
           echo  <td>. $row['email'] .</td>
           echo  <td>. $row['message'] .</td>
           echo </tr>

 }

echo "</tbody>
 </table>";
```

Can someone help me why is this making the error? I couldnt find anything helpful in the internet.
**EDIT**: I have added materialize-css css files with the link in the header and i have included the header as well.

Comment: You got `echo <tr>` Did you forget to put the `<tr>` in quotes along with the `<td>`s, as well as include the semicolons at the end of each line? i.e. `echo '<tr>';` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that was a problem. However, the main problem exists.
I dunno if i got it right but its like echo "<tr>";  instead of echo '<tr>'; . Is it wrong?

Comment: In PHP you can use either a single quote or double quote to specify a string. (also the heredoc syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) There are some differences with the various methods. The single vs double helps with interchanging quotes in html, like `echo '<div class="message">hi</div>`

Comment: O now i remember. ' '  is for making html codes not to be parsed and " " is for making them parsed or vice versa!

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake. You are not wrapping the data you want to echo in quotes, so try doing it like this.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[email]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[message]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: No bro. I actually had that but it still makes error http 500.

Comment: This page isn’t working
sabashelter.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Hmm that not much help is it.